# Is $V(y) \subset \mathbb C^2$ not an affine toric variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, definition, affine-varieties, toric-varieties

From Toric Varieties by Cox, Little, Schenck:

> An affine toric variety is an irreducible affine variety $V$ containing a torus $T_N\cong (\mathbb C^*)^n$ as a Zariski open subset such that the action of $T_N$ on itself extends to an algebraic action of $T_N$ on $V$. (By algebraic action, we mean an action $T_N\times V \to V$ given by a morphism.)

> **Proposition 1.1.11.** An ideal $I\subset \mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_s]$is toric if and only if it is prime and generated by binomials.

The affine variety $V(y) \subset \mathbb C^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C^1$ and we know that $\mathbb C^1$ is an affine toric variety. But the prime ideal $(y) \subset \mathbb C[x,y]$ is not generated by binomials.

Also, $V(y) \cap (\mathbb C^*)^2 = \varnothing$.

Is $V(y) \subset \mathbb C^2$ not an affine toric variety?

Comment: Can you include your definition of binomials, please? For instance, it might be the case that $y-0$ is a binomial which would resolve your confusion. (In fact, I bet this is the case!)

Comment: @HankScorpio Binomial is not defined in this book, but in Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms: A monomial in $x_1,\dots, x_n$ is a product of the form $x^{a_1}x^{a_2}\cdots·x^{a_n}$ where all of the exponents $a_1 ,\dots, a_n$ are nonnegative integers. So, $0$ is not a monomial.

Comment: Yeah, I would disagree. Also, you haven't even specified whether a toric variety should be a variety cut out by a toric ideal - I imagine it's not difficult to come up with embeddings of $\Bbb A^1$ in to some high-dimensional affine space where the ideal is not generated by binomials. (Being generated by binomials is not even independent of the coordinates, I don't think.)

Comment: @HankScorpio It is a known fact that toric varieties arise from toric ideals, and also that given a toric variety, we get a toric ideal. This is mentioned in chap 1, sec 2 of the Toric Varieties book, page 14 and page 16.

Comment: Regarding independence of coordinates, the statement should be something like: Let $T^N$ act on $k[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N]$ in the standard way and let $I$ be an ideal of $k[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N]$. Call $I$ a "toric ideal" if there is a subtorus $H$ of $T^N$ for which $I$ is $H$-invariant and $\text{Spec}\ k[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]/I$ is a toric variety for the action of $H$. Then we want a classification of toric ideals.

Comment: The statement should be something like every toric ideal is generated by binomials and by individual variables, but I don't know the exact statement. As the OP points out, just binomials aren't enough.